# Simplify product of roots containing goniometric functions

Tags: maxima

In Maxima, I am trying to simplify the expression

```
sqrt(1 - sin(x)) * sqrt(1 + sin(x))
```

to yield

```
cos(x)
```

I properly restricted the definition of `x`

```
declare(x, real) $
assume(x > 0, x < %pi/2) $
```

and tried several simplification commands including `radcan`, `trigsimp`, `trigreduce` and `trigexpand`, but without any success. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try trigsimp(rootscontract(expr))

Comment: This works almost perfect, except that it does not seem to take advantage of restricting x to the interval (0, pi/2), where the abs(cos) = cos. Any idea if this can be achieved as well?

Comment: Yes, the "assume" system isn't as smart as it could be.

As a workaround, use assume(cos(x)>0)

Answer (score 1):

The restrictions you assert do not uniquely determine the simplified result you request.

It would seem both harmless and obviously unnecessary to declare or assume the following:
declare(9, real)
assume(9>0)

and yet,  sqrt(9)  is still the set {-3, +3}, mathematically speaking, as opposed to "what I learned in 6th grade".

Stavros' suggestion give  |cos(x)|,  which is not quite what the original questioner wanted.

Another way of getting the same result, one which may more explicitly exhibit the -in general falseness - of the result, is to square and then use the semi-bogus sqrt, that attempts to pick the positive answer.

trigsimp (sqrt(expand(expr^2)));

If you think this is a way of simplifying expr, note that it changes -3 to 3.

Comment: I see your point, but for me a real square root is a single-valued function (as opposed to "solution of x^2 = y") and I would like Maxima to treat it as such here.

Comment: Maxima generally assumes the positive square root in many cases:

With positive numerical arguments, it consistently returns the positive root, e.g., sqrt(2.0)=>1.414... The *sign* function assumes the positive root: sign(sqrt(x)) => pz.

sqrt(x^2) simplifies to abs(x) precisely to ensure the positive root. If you want sqrt(x^2) to simplify to x, you can set radexpand:'all$ Be careful... this does *not* guarantee the positive root:

radexpand:'all$
ex: sqrt(x^2)$
subst(-3,x,ex) => -3

Comment: The function sqrt(u)  in Maxima is really  u^(1/2) internally.  So if you think about consistency with other powers, like u^(1/4)  or u^(1/3),  what would you like to see?

Comment: @RichardFateman: These are the same to me; I consider f(x) = x^(1/4) to be a single-valued function on a given Riemann plane that ought to be specified in the documentation. If "sqrt" was automatically a multi-valued function, why would Maxima return "[x = - sqrt(a), x = sqrt(a)]" as an answer to "solve(x^2 = a, x)", instead of simply "[x = sqrt(a)]" covering both cases.

Comment: Several issues arise. 1. It must be possible for you to choose/ specify the Riemann surface, or for that matter, for the documentation to identify it.  Do you have a suggested notation for this? When there are an arbitrary number of parameters, the stuff that you learn in courses may not suffice.  You learn about functions of a single complex variable.  Constructive mathematics involving functions of MULTIPLE complex variables is basically nonexistent, and that is what a CAS must, in principle, address. 2. the result from solve is a SET encoded as a list, covering both cases.